# Pronunciation of 什么

Tags: pronunciation, phonology

什么 (shénme) sounds to my ears more like (shéme).

Assuming I'm hearing correctly, is this just a common contraction of this word, or is the sequence "-n" + "m-" *generally* contracted to "-m-"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Zhang and Yang (2007:157–165) classifies consonantal assimilation (輔音同化) in Mandarin into three types:

   - Progressive assimilation (前化後, lit. prior converts latter)
   - Regressive assimilation (後化前, lit. latter converts prior)
   - Bidirectional assimilation (前後互化, lit. prior and latter convert each other)

**Examples of regressive assimilation**

2. **/n/ → [m] / _ [p pʰ m]** (= all /n/ before [p], [pʰ], or [m] become [m]). All bilabial consonants in Mandarin exert an effect on an immediately preceding /n/. `什麼` naturally follows this rule.

   |  | Before | After | Pinyin |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 麵包 | /mjɛn˥˩ paʊ˥˥/ | [mjɛm˥˩ paʊ˥˥] | miàn bāo |
   | 亂跑 | /lwan˥˩ pʰaʊ˨˩˦/ | [lwam˥˩ pʰaʊ˨˩˦] | luàn pǎo |
   | 難免 | /nan˧˥ mjɛn˨˩˦/ | [nam˧˥ mjɛn˨˩˦] | nán miǎn |
3. **/n/ → [ŋ̟] / _ [k kʰ x]**. I added the advanced diacritic for [ŋ] because Zhang and Yang claims the inherent nature of /n/ is still stronger than assimilation, so the result is not exactly velar. Also, notice in the first and third examples how the final has not changed from [aŋ] to [ɑŋ], so the result of assimilation is also not exactly *ang* in pinyin, either.

   |  | Before | After | Pinyin |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 戰國 | /ʈ͡ʂan˥˩ kuɔ˧˥/ | [ʈ͡ʂaŋ̟˥˩ kuɔ˧˥] | Zhàn'guó |
   | 辛苦 | /ɕɪn˥˥ kʰu˨˩˦/ | [ɕɪŋ̟˥˥ kʰu˨˩˦] | xīn kǔ |
   | 山花 | /ʂan˥˥ xwa˥˥/ | [ʂaŋ̟˥˥ xwa˥˥] | shān huā |
4. **/n/ → [ɲ] / _ [t͡ɕ t͡ɕʰ ɕ]** (palatalisation before pinyin *j q x*), but **/n/ → [ɳ] / _ [ʈ͡ʂ ʈ͡ʂʰ ʂ]** (retroflexisation before pinyin *zh ch sh*). Personally I think these are less conspicuous.

   |  | Before | After | Pinyin |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 班級 | /pan˥˥ t͡ɕi˧˥/ | [paɲ˥˥ t͡ɕi˧˥] | bān jí |
   | 感情 | /kan˨˩ t͡ɕʰɪŋ˧˥/ | [kaɲ˨˩ t͡ɕʰɪŋ˧˥] | gǎn qíng |
   | 看戲 | /kʰan˥˩ ɕi˥˩/ | [kʰaɲ˥˩ ɕi˥˩] | kàn xì |
   | 班長 | /pan˥˥ ʈ͡ʂɑŋ˨˩˦/ | [paɳ˥˥ ʈ͡ʂɑŋ˨˩˦] | bān zhǎng |
   | 難吃 | /nan˧˥ ʈ͡ʂʰɚ˥˥/ | [naɳ˧˥ ʈ͡ʂʰɚ˥˥] | nán chī |
   | 天山 | /tʰjɛn˥˥ ʂan˥˥/ | [tʰjɛɳ˥˥ ʂan˥˥] | tiān shān |

**Example of progressive assimilation**

5. **/∅/ → [ŋ] / [ŋ] _** (= all /∅/ after [ŋ] become [ŋ]).

   |  | Before | After | Pinyin |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 嫦娥 | /ʈ͡ʂʰɑŋ˧˥ ɤ˧˥/ | [ʈ͡ʂʰɑŋ˧˥ ŋɤ˧˥] | Cháng'é |

**Example of bidirectional assimilation**

6. **/n ∅/ → [ŋ̟ ŋ̟]**. It is as if the third and fifth rules are combined.

   |  | Before | After | Pinyin |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 專案 | /ʈ͡ʂwan˥˥ an˥˩/ | [ʈ͡ʂwaŋ̟˥˥ ŋ̟an˥˩] | zhuān àn |
   | 天鵝 | /tʰjɛn˥˥ ɤ˧˥/ | [tʰjɛŋ̟˥˥ ŋ̟ɤ˧˥] | tiān é |

Reference: Zhang Bennan & Yang Ruowei (2007). [普通話連讀音變]. Hong Kong: Commercial Press.